# How to apply gravity to bouncing balls in javascript -

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to move from having a ball bounce back and forth around a canvas to having some gravity and eventually dropping.
I know i need to change the velocity when it reaches the bottom but i have no idea how this should be done and coded.

I am a completely new JS student, with no physics background - how hard is this going to be? I'm quite happy to learn etc. I tried having balls collide and come off at correct angles but that seems way above me for now.

```
var canvas,
    ctx,
    cx = 100,
    cy = 150,
    vx = 0,
    vy = 5,
    radius = 30;

function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    circle();
}

function circle() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    requestAnimationFrame(circle);

    if (cx + radius > canvas.width || cx - radius < 0)
    vx = -vx;
    if (cy + radius > canvas.height || cy - radius < 0)
    vy = -vy;

    cx += vx;  
    cy += vy;
}
```

I've taken out cx movement just for up/down animation and the circle draw codes for space
What would be the next step?

Will i be multiplying its current velocity by a number like 0.8 on collision and where/how?

Forgive basicness/horrible written code - gotta start somewhere!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You were very close, think of the gravity as a constant downwards velocity increment, so in each step you need to add that to your `vy` calculation.

> "I know i need to change the velocity when it reaches the bottom"`

That is not true because gravity affects objects ALL the time. When you touch the bottom, things like material dampening and surface friction can happen.

```js
var canvas,
  ctx,
  cx = 100,
  cy = 100,
  vx = 2,
  vy = 5,
  radius = 5,
  gravity = 0.2,
  damping = 0.9,
  traction = 0.8,
  paused = false;
  ;

function init() {

  canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  canvas.width = 300;
  canvas.height = 150;

  circle();
}

function circle() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  if (!paused)
    requestAnimationFrame(circle);

  if (cx + radius >= canvas.width) {
    vx = -vx * damping;
    cx = canvas.width - radius;
  } else if (cx - radius <= 0) {
    vx = -vx * damping;
    cx = radius;
  }
  if (cy + radius >= canvas.height) {
    vy = -vy * damping;
    cy = canvas.height - radius;
    // traction here
    vx *= traction;
  } else if (cy - radius <= 0) {
    vy = -vy * damping;
    cy = radius;
  }

  vy += gravity; // <--- this is it

  cx += vx;
  cy += vy;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  ctx.fill();
}

init();

// fancy/irrelevant mouse grab'n'throw stuff below
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);

function handleMouseDown(e) {
  cx = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  cy = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
  vx = vy = 0;
  paused = true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
  vx = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft - cx;
  vy = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop - cy;
  paused = false;
  circle();
}
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid black; cursor: crosshair;}
p {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
<p>Throw the ball by holding and releasing the left mouse button on the canvas (reverse slingshot)</p>
```

Comment: You're welcome. You probably need to add wall damping next in order to make it more realistic. About the bottom behaviour - it depends what you want to do. The glitch happens because the ball still manages to drop below the edge at some point. To fix it, you can always restore the ball inside the field when the collision happens.

Comment: How would i go about doing that @Shomz, ignore my last comment as that made no sense btw. Is there a way to get it from stop going under the canvas when it has stopped bouncing?

Comment: I've added the traction as well. Does it all make sense now?

Comment: thanks again, I kind of understand it @Shomz, the damping is just on every contact the ball makes with an edge yes and reduces the velocityX/Y by 0.9? 
Im not too sure what vx *= traction means other than it adds the traction. Is it just again vx movement reduced each bounce by traction?

Comment: You're welcome. They are very similar - damping happens when it touches a wall, you were correct. It multiplies the appropriate velocity by the damping factor So, it affects the horizontal speed when it touches the left/right edges and the vertical speed when it touches the top/bottom edges; while traction affects the horizontal speed when the ball touches the bottom edge only (this could also work for the other 3 edges as well, but I wanted you to see the difference). And `vx *= traction` is the same as `vx = vx * traction`, just a shorthand way to write it.

Comment: Extremely helpful! @Shomz thank you again. I have one last question and i'll stop bugging you but with the extra bit you added (awesome btw) could you explain what cx = e.pageX - canvasoffsetLeft; mean. More so the pageX and canvasoffsetLeft (and canvasoffsetTop)??

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help! Ah, you should probably ignore those for now. It's the way of fetching the mouse coordinates on the canvas element, so I could reposition the ball and recalculate its velocity when you release the mouse button. It's just a little something I added to make the example nicer and so you can play with it more - it's completely unrelated to the question.