# How to delete particular circle when user creates multiple circles by dragging mouse on screen using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I created circles using canvas but can't delete the same on double click.`

```js
var canvas,
context, shapes,
dragging = false, draggingtoMove = false,
    dragStartLocation,dragEndLocation,
    snapshot;
 var numShapes;
function initiate() {
    numShapes = 100;
    shapes = [];
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
     context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', dragStop, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('dblclick', dblclickerase);
}
function dblclickerase(evt)
{
   var i;
  //We are going to pay attention to the layering order of the objects so that if a mouse down occurs over more than object,
  //only the topmost one will be dragged.
  var highestIndex = -1;
  
  //getting mouse position correctly, being mindful of resizing that may have occured in the browser:
  var bRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  mouseX = (evt.clientX - bRect.left)*(canvas.width/bRect.width);
  mouseY = (evt.clientY - bRect.top)*(canvas.height/bRect.height);
    
  //find which shape was clicked
  for (i=0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
   if (hitTest(shapes[i], mouseX, mouseY)) {
    //draggingtoMove = true;
    if (i > highestIndex) {
     // here i want to delete the circle on double click but not getting logic, I can get mouse location  but how to select the circle and delete it 
    }
   }
  }
}
function getCanvasCoordinates(event) {
    var x = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        y = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };
}

function takeSnapshot() {
    snapshot = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function restoreSnapshot() {
    context.putImageData(snapshot, 0, 0);
}


function draw(position) {
     var radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((dragStartLocation.x - position.x), 2) + Math.pow((dragStartLocation.y - position.y), 2));
        var i=0;
  var tempX;
  var tempY;
  var tempRad;
  var tempR;
  var tempG;
  var tempB;
  var tempColor;
   tempRad = radius;
   tempX = dragStartLocation.x;
   tempY = dragStartLocation.y;
   tempColor = getRndColor();
   tempShape = {x:tempX, y:tempY, rad:tempRad, color:tempColor};
   shapes.push(tempShape);
   context.beginPath();
   context.arc(tempX, tempY, tempRad, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
   //context.closePath();
            context.fillStyle = tempColor;
   context.fill();
   i++;
}

function dragStart(evt) {
    dragging = true;
    //if (dragging == true) {
        dragStartLocation = getCanvasCoordinates(evt);
        takeSnapshot();
    //}

    }

 function hitTest(shape,mx,my) {
  
  var dx;
  var dy;
  dx = mx - shape.x;
  dy = my - shape.y;
  
  //a "hit" will be registered if the distance away from the center is less than the radius of the circular object  
  return (dx*dx + dy*dy < shape.rad*shape.rad);
 }

function drag(event) {
    var position;
    if (dragging === true) {
        restoreSnapshot();
        position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
        draw(position);
    }
}

function dragStop(event) {
    dragging = false;
    restoreSnapshot();
   var position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
  dragEndLocation = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
    draw(position);
}

function getRndColor() {
    var r = 255 * Math.random() | 0,
        g = 255 * Math.random() | 0,
        b = 255 * Math.random() | 0;
    return 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
}

function eraseCanvas() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

addEventListener("load",initiate);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1020" height="640"></canvas>
        <button onclick="eraseCanvas()" style="float: right;">Reset</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

> My question is how to delete the circle when double click on same, I
>   added 'dblClick' eventListener but still I am only able to perform the 'clearRect'
>   which will only clear the rectangle from start and end location which is little odd. Another thing I can't change the color to white which will not be valid.point as if my circle overlaps another will look odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete what you draw on the canvas like that. Once it's drawn on the canvas, it stays there and you have no way to access it except to read the pixel data - but that won't solve your problem because you can have overlapping circles of the same color.

To solve the issue, you must keep track of drawn circles, and redraw **the full canvas** every time it's needed (when adding a new circle, removing an old one, etc.). That way, when you want to delete a circle, you'd simply remove it from the list of circles (a simple array would work). But the important thing is that you need to clear and redraw the full canvas.

Summary: while having your canvas constantly redrawn (either on every tick or when a user interaction happens), your click'n'drag function should only be adding the circle to the circle list (specifying data like x, y, radius, color), while double-clicking a circle would look up that circle in the list, and remove it.

Comment: Means you are trying to say that I need to create a new canvas by clearing the old one (circles on which i double clicked) and then again reset the new canvas with remaining ones? Ain't there any possibility to fix this code only.

Comment: Thanks @Shomz And one more question I was thinking just a while ago If want to drag a circle from one position to another then what steps probably do I follow.??

Comment: It would be very difficult to fix your current code because after you draw something on the canvas, you no longer have the access to it except for reading the pixel values - so in order to fix your code, you'd have to come up with a circle-recognition tool which works on the pixel level and it would be insanely difficult to handle with overlapping circles.

Comment: You're welcome. For your second comment: that would be easy with my approach from above: you'd recognize the clicked circle from the list and simply change its `x` and `y` parameters while dragging.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with that! Let me know if you need more help. :)

Comment: Oh, here's one of my old answers with canvas, it doesn't quite feature the drag'n'drop functionality like you want to build, but it uses drag'n'drop to "launch" the balls: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29982343/965907  See if some of that code helps you.