# bounce physics for html 5 canvas platformer style game

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I am creating a platformer style game and have set up some physics. I want to make it so that when the player jumps and falls, it bounces and comes to a stop. Please, can someone help? Thanks.
Jsfiddle link to my code : https://jsfiddle.net/fezzie07/nfbv5oLd/153/#&togetherjs=HH8otvf7hA

html :

```
<html>

<body>
 <canvas id="c" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

css :

```
#c {
   background-color: #202020;
   border-style: dashed;
   border-color: black;
   border-width: 1px;
}
```

javascript :

```
 var fps, canvas, context, controller, gamePiece, gameEnemy, loop;

fps = 60;

canvas = document.getElementById("c");

context = canvas.getContext("2d");

controller = {

  left: false,
  right: false,
  up: false,
  keyListener: function(event) {

    var key_state = (event.type == "keydown") ? true : false;

    switch (event.keyCode) {

      case 37: // left key
        controller.left = key_state;
        break;
      case 38: // up key
        controller.up = key_state;
        break;
      case 39: // right key
        controller.right = key_state;
        break;

    }

  }

};

gamePiece = {
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height / 2,
  w: 10,
  h: 10,
  yVel: 0,
  xVel: 0,
  jumping: false,
}

gameEnemy = {

}

loop = function() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  draw();
  move();
  collision();
  if (controller.up && gamePiece.jumping == false) {
    gamePiece.yVel -= 15;
    gamePiece.jumping = true;

  }
  if (controller.left) {
    gamePiece.xVel -= 0.5;
  }
  if(controller.right) {
    gamePiece.xVel += 0.5;
  }
}

function draw() {
  context.fillStyle = "#afeeee"
  context.fillRect(gamePiece.x, gamePiece.y, gamePiece.w, gamePiece.h);
  context.strokeStyle = "#f08080";
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(0, canvas.height - 16);
  context.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height - 16);
  context.stroke();
}

function move() {
  gamePiece.yVel += 1.5;
  gamePiece.y += gamePiece.yVel;
  gamePiece.x += gamePiece.xVel;
  gamePiece.xVel *= 0.9;
  gamePiece.yVel *= 0.9;
}

function collision() {
  if (gamePiece.y > canvas.height - 16 - gamePiece.h) {
    gamePiece.y = canvas.height - 16 - gamePiece.h;
    gamePiece.yVel = 0;
    gamePiece.jumping = false;
  }
}

window.setInterval(loop, 1000 / fps);
window.addEventListener("keydown", controller.keyListener)
window.addEventListener("keyup", controller.keyListener);
```

Comment: also, if you can improve my code in any way please let me know

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982228/how-to-apply-gravity-to-bouncing-balls-in-javascript/29982343#29982343 I wrote this answer long ago, it has a full bouncing ball code, see if it helps... Also there might be more answers here on SO that you can make use of.

Comment: i have checked everywhere and can not find answres on SO that help me. i will check the link. Thanks

Comment: This did not help as i want it to come to a halt after 1 or 2 bounces

Comment: Count the bounces and set the velocity to zero when needed.

Comment: The following answer is a platform jumper, I have made a quick mod to the answer to give the player a single bounce on landing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46920237/3877726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function collision(), instead of doing

```
 gamePiece.yVel = 0;
```

You could do

```
gamePiece.yVel = -gamePiece.yVel;
```

If it too bouncy, multiply it by a damping value,

```
var yDamp = 0.5;
gamePiece.yVel = -gamePiece.yVel * yDamp;
```

Finally, to prevent jumping when bouncing

```
gamePiece.jumping = gamePiece.yVel > 1;
```